# bitcoind not sending index nor blocks to inbound connections

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

Currently, I am following the recommendation of running a full node on my desktop with bitcoind; it has most of the blockchain downloaded (~680000 blocks) and is not pruned. Then I have two laptops that I will be running bitcoin-qt on that will only connect to my full node. Unfortunately, I am having trouble with bitcoind sending the index and blocks to the inbound connections from the bitcoin-qt laptops. My configuration files, node info, and peer info are included below. Thanks for your suggestions.

desktop bitcoind `/etc/bitcoin.conf`

```
rpcauth=root:******
rpcauth=_bitcoind:******
[main]
[test]
[signet]
[regtest]
```

laptop bitcoin-qt `~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`

```
connect=192.168.1.197:8333
```

desktop bitcoind daemon control script `/etc/rc.d/bitcoind`

```
#!/bin/ksh
#
# $OpenBSD: bitcoind.rc,v 1.2 2018/07/15 22:03:50 bentley Exp $

daemon="/usr/local/bin/bitcoind"
daemon_timeout="300"
daemon_user="_bitcoind"

datadir="/home/bitcoin"
conf="/etc/bitcoin.conf"
daemon_flags="-daemon -conf=$conf -datadir=${datadir}"

. /etc/rc.d/rc.subr

rc_reload=NO


rc_cmd $1
```

`bitcoin-cli -getinfo` to bitcoind on the desktop, it returns:

```
{
  "version": 210100,
  "blocks": 684628,
  "headers": 718323,
  "verificationprogress": 0.90065025371744,
  "timeoffset": -1,
  "connections": {
    "in": 2,
    "out": 1,
    "total": 3
  },
  "proxy": "",
  "difficulty": 25046487590083.27,
  "chain": "main",
  "relayfee": 0.00001000,
  "warnings": ""
}
```

When I run `getpeerinfo` in the bitcoin-qt console, I get:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "addr": "192.168.1.197:8333",
    "addrbind": "192.168.1.174:58377",
    "network": "not_publicly_routable",
    "services": "0000000000000409",
    "servicesnames": [
      "NETWORK",
      "WITNESS",
      "NETWORK_LIMITED"
    ],
    "relaytxes": true,
    "lastsend": 1642006419,
    "lastrecv": 1642006299,
    "last_transaction": 0,
    "last_block": 0,
    "bytessent": 693,
    "bytesrecv": 18317,
    "conntime": 1642005880,
    "timeoffset": 0,
    "pingtime": 0.002229,
    "minping": 0.001617,
    "pingwait": 6.439448,
    "version": 70016,
    "subver": "/Satoshi:0.21.1/",
    "inbound": false,
    "bip152_hb_to": false,
    "bip152_hb_from": false,
    "startingheight": 684595,
    "synced_headers": -1,
    "synced_blocks": -1,
    "inflight": [
    ],
    "addr_processed": 1003,
    "addr_rate_limited": 0,
    "permissions": [
    ],
    "minfeefilter": 0.09170997,
    "bytessent_per_msg": {
      "feefilter": 32,
      "getaddr": 24,
      "getheaders": 93,
      "ping": 160,
      "pong": 96,
      "sendaddrv2": 24,
      "sendcmpct": 66,
      "sendheaders": 24,
      "verack": 24,
      "version": 126,
      "wtxidrelay": 24
    },
    "bytesrecv_per_msg": {
      "addrv2": 17773,
      "feefilter": 32,
      "ping": 96,
      "pong": 128,
      "sendaddrv2": 24,
      "sendcmpct": 66,
      "sendheaders": 24,
      "verack": 24,
      "version": 126,
      "wtxidrelay": 24
    },
    "connection_type": "manual"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the whole blockchain has to be synced before it will send the index and blocks to inbound requests.

Explained in this issue: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/6971